# How to configure Puma for Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

Using Amazon Web Services (AWS), I created an Elastic Beanstalk app with the latest platform version of Amazon Linux running Ruby (Puma).

Should I add a Puma configuration file (such as `config/puma.rb`) to my app? And, if so, what should I put in it? Specifically, what should I set for threads & workers?